# rails fragment cache store

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am unable to figure out where my cached fragments are being stored. What is the default location for fragment caching.

```
Cached fragment hit: views/listed_products (0.1ms)
```

I cannot find anything in the rails_root/public or rails_root/tmp/cache dirs

thanks,
ash

Answer (score 5):

It's probably [MemoryStore](http://guides.rails.info/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores), which is used if `tmp/cache` does not exist. I can't tell from the current post if it actually exists for you or not.

Comment: 'tmp/cache' exists but nothing in there. So how does one find out?

Comment: in that case, just open `script/console`, and `p Rails.cache`, unless you're on an old version of rails.

Comment: I recently encountered a problem where it wasn't caching fragments. The directory 'tmp/cache' didn't exist, and when I created it, everything worked fine. Not completely related to the original question, but your response helped me work out the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I found it inside tmp/cache. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try out:

```
Rails.cache.cache_path
```